CSS grids not playing nice with overflow?
This is a very similar issue to my previous question. I learned a whole lot from that, but it doesn't seem to work in this particular situation, of which I've created a simplified mock-up here:


let box = document.getElementById('textbox');
for (let i = 0; i < 100; i++)
  box.innerHTML += 'Lorem Ipsum ';
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr;
  border: solid 4px blue;
  padding: 16px;
}

.fullscreen {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  border: solid 4px red;
}

#textbox {
  padding: 4px;
  width: 100px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  border: solid green 4px;
}
<div class="fullscreen grid">
  <div class="grid" style="grid-template-rows: min-content 1fr; gap: 16px;">
    <div style="border: solid green 4px; padding: 16px;"></div>
    <div id=textbox></div>
  </div>
</div>



The red div is intended to take up the whole screen - no more, no less.
The bottom green div is a scrollable text box. However, in this specific configuration, I can't get it to stay within the grid layout and padding I've prescribed.
In you were to remove the intermediate blue div, or remove the upper green div, then the textbox behaves correctly, but of course that destroys the rest of the existing design. It also works if you specify a finite size for the grid row containing the textbox (such as 100px), but that too defeats the purpose, as I want it to occupy the whole vertical space.
Any idea what's going on and how I might resolve this?

min-height:0 to .grid

Thank you for that solution. I'm very curious now, though, why does that work? Why does specifying a minimum height effectively affect the maximum height?
